# Shortest way to check if array contains more then one element

Tags: c#

What is the shortest way (using the fewest characters) to check if an array contains more then one element in C#?

Is it?

```
if ( array.Length > 1 )
```

Comment: Use the Length property

Comment: Why do you care? Just use the code you are most comfortable with even if `try { array.DefaultIfEmpty().Single();  //  has one or zero } catch { // has multiple entries } `

Comment: A C# array can be null and you do not either show the definition of the array nor check for null so possibly throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

With arrays, you should check the property `Length`:

```
array.Length > 1
```

The Linq method `Count()` will also work but you don't really need an extension method for this since the property `Length` will do the job just fine.

Also, if readability is a concern, you can do:

```
bool arrayContainsMoreThanOneElement = array.Length > 1;

if (arrayContainsMoreThanOneElement)
{
    // some code here
}
```